# Converge API : error 6042 - Invalid Request Format

Tags: xml, curl, payment-gateway, payment

Request Url:

https://api.convergepay.com/VirtualMerchant/processxml.do

Here is my sample XML Request:

```xml
xmldata=<txn>
<ssl_merchant_id>my_merchant_id</ssl_merchant_id>
<ssl_user_id>my_user_id</ssl_user_id>
<ssl_pin>my_pin</ssl_pin>
<ssl_transaction_type>ccsale</ssl_transaction_type><ssl_card_number>4000000000000002</ssl_card_number>
<ssl_exp_ date>1124</ssl_exp_date>
<ssl_amount>1.00</ssl_amount>
<ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator>1</ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator>
<ssl_cvv2cvc2>786</ssl_cvv2cvc2>
<ssl_first_name>adolfo</ssl_first_name></txn>
</txn>
```

My Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<txn>
    <errorCode>6042</errorCode>
    <errorName>Invalid Request Format</errorName>
    <errorMessage>XML request is not well-formed or request is incomplete.</errorMessage>
</txn>
```

Example request look like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml'  -d 'xmldata=<txn><ssl_merchant_id>my_merchant_id</ssl_merchant_id><ssl_user_id>my_user_id</ssl_user_id><ssl_pin>my_pin</ssl_pin><ssl_transaction_type>ccsale</ssl_transaction_type><ssl_card_number>4000000000000002</ssl_card_number><ssl_exp_ date>1124</ssl_exp_date><ssl_amount>1.00</ssl_amount><ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator>1</ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator><ssl_cvv2cvc2>786</ssl_cvv2cvc2><ssl_first_name>adolfo</ssl_first_name></txn>' https://api.convergepay.com/VirtualMerchant/processxml.do
```

what the trouble with my request?

Answer (score 7):

Change your HEADER fields:values to the following:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a space in the expiration date XML element in your request: `<ssl_exp _date>`.

Remove the space and that might work.