# XML request is not well-formed or request is incomplete to call Elavon api to generate token

Tags: python-3.x, xml, payment-gateway

I am trying to send an xml request to generate token
the code is

```
import requests

url = "https://api.demo.convergepay.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/processxml.do"

dataXml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<txn>
    <ssl_merchant_id>mercentId</ssl_merchant_id>
    <ssl_user_id>userID</ssl_user_id>
    <ssl_pin>sslPin</ssl_pin>
    <ssl_transaction_type>ccgettoken</ssl_transaction_type>
    <ssl_card_number>0000000000000000</ssl_card_number>
    <ssl_exp_date>1222</ssl_exp_date>
    <ssl_avs_address>7300</ssl_avs_address>
    <ssl_avs_zip>12345</ssl_avs_zip>
    <ssl_verify>N</ssl_verify>
</txn>
"""


x = requests.post(url, data=dataXml)


print(x.text)
```

But i am getting below error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<txn><errorCode>6042</errorCode><errorName>Invalid Request Format</errorName><errorMessage>XML request is not well-formed or request is incomplete.</errorMessage></txn>
```

What is the wrong with my request ?

Comment: The error diagnostic rather crudely covers two broad categories, but know that your XML is well-formed.   Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65137443/290085

Comment: Thanks for response. But I am getting the same errormessage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converge API : error 6042 - Invalid Request Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137443/converge-api-error-6042-invalid-request-format)

Answer (score 0):

I think that setting the Content-Type header is the key.
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Also, I would recommend using lxml.builder to create the XML.
Here is an example

```
xml_req = lxml.builder.E.txn(
      lxml.builder.E.ssl_merchant_id(mercentId)
      lxml.builder.E.ssl_user_id(userID)
      # ...
     )
dataXml = 'xmldata={}'.format(lxml.etree.tostring(xml_req))
```